# Binding data for tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol

First of all i'm a newbie on MVVM pattern and C# / XAML developpment. Sorry for the inconveniant.

So the aim is to create a complete application including buttons, tabcontrol and use bindings and commands to gather them all correctly.

Each button represent a specific object which has its own information (name, id, serial number, ...). All these buttons are represented in a specific view which is on a top of the window. At the bottom of this window, i need to show a table with several items and content inside associated to the button pressed.

The problem here is the table. I need to display the information of the clicked object inside the table and the content inside can vary for all tabitems. And one other thing is that when one button in particulary is pressed, the view of the table totally change and display other information.

My questions are :

- Do i need to create one model for each of my button / object AND an associated viewModel to it ?
- The view including all of the buttons can be a separated view from the table and both of them will be in MainView ?
- Can i represent data inside the table like a scrollviewer and is it possible to add new line wih other informations from the model when click on it ?

I hope my explanation is enough to helpor so here is a schematic representation of my application showing different context. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb2Vs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5USBd.png)

Thanks all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> - Do i need to create one model for each of my button / object AND an    associated viewModel to it ?

You can go both ways. If your `model` communicates with different `API` and requires you to use different `contract` then yes use different `models`. Otherwise I would suggest using one. About `ViewModel` it is as well up to you it could be done both ways. I would suggest separation but as of in question I did not find any information about the size of the application itself so it all depends on the size and concern segragation.

> - The view including all of the buttons can be a separated view from    the table and both of them will be in MainView?

You still need root view so everything should in the same view. I could suggest creating a new `UserControl` for each of the `TabWindows` then simply just `collapse` or make it `visible` depending on button command invoked.

> - Can i represent data inside the table like a scrollviewer and is it
>     possible to add new line wih other informations from the model when
>     click on it ?

You can add `ScrollViewer` into each of the `tabs` in `TabControl`. I am not quite sure what is the question on the second part of it but I would suggest to use `ObservableCollection` with `ItemsSource` to dynamically add items to your data table.

More information about MVVM pattern and its applications can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple).